# Library for making static websites with HAML/SASS/CSS framework

Tags: html, css, haml, sass, compass-sass

I'm looking for a library or a collection of libraries that work together with the following requirements:

- HAML and SASS can be used.
- Have a small server capability to see HAML/SASS compiled every time I refresh my browser. (I don't want to start a fresh Rails app, though.)
- Works with popular CSS frameworks. (Doesn't have to be all, but major ones like 960gs and Blueprint)

Compass seems to be promissing, but it doesn't seem to support HAML. At least I'm looking for information that make Compass and HAML together.

**Edit** chriseppstein gave the list of cool stuff. I'll make a link to each one.

- http://staticmatic.rubyforge.org/
- http://github.com/tdreyno/middleman
- http://nanoc.stoneship.org/
- http://webby.rubyforge.org/user-manual/
- http://github.com/jlong/serve

Comment: Thanks I was on my iphone at the time and making links would have been hard...

Comment: Note that Webby development is effectively discontinued. Most discussions on alternatives recommend Nanoc.

Comment: For examples on using nanoc and compass together: https://github.com/adamstac/nanoc-bootstrap and https://github.com/ddfreyne/nanoc-bootstrap-compass

Comment: Serve now compiles Sass etc, using a folder-tree kinda system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several of these:

- [staticmatic](https://github.com/staticmatic/staticmatic)
- [middleman](http://middlemanapp.com/)
- [nanoc](http://nanoc.stoneship.org/)
- [webby](http://webby.rubyforge.org/)

All of these support haml and sass and can be easily configured to work with compass too.

Additionally, there is "serve", which is just a simple webserver.

Answer (score -1):

I use Prepros, and I'm satisfied with it.