# Automate Haml & Sass with Sublime Text 2 for Windows

Tags: html, css, haml, sass, sublimetext2

I am a front-end guy using Windows for design and html/js/css coding. My work is separate from the back-end guy using .NET. I am also new to Haml/Sass thing as well as Ruby. And definitely not using Rails. After few search, I decided to pick Sublime Text 2 for Sass/Haml support and get rid of my old Notepad++. My first question is:

***1. What is the best practice / efficiency to automatically convert whole folder of Haml (primary) and/or Sass to static documents (html/css)?***

I have a separate solution for Sass by setting the "watch". I was searching for Haml automatic conversion solution and found few options:
[Library for making static websites with HAML/SASS/CSS framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161517/library-for-making-static-websites-with-haml-sass-css-framework)

***2. Should I use StaticMatic?***

Google search said it is the best. But there seems no update for 2 years
https://github.com/staticmatic/staticmatic

There is also this site (Is it the same?): http://staticmatic.rubyforge.org/how_to_use.html

If I use StaticMatic, I can setup a build system in Sublime Text to run from the Build Menu (http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_processing/build_systems.html)

***3. OR should I go with all-in-one solution like this (may cost few bucks)? Is there free one?***

http://fireapp.handlino.com/

I don't mind to have Sass -watch running separately and another polling mechanism for Haml. I just want to make sure I have the "latest" out there.

Hope to get some advise for my unique situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is Middleman
http://middlemanapp.com/

It's the replacement for out-dated StaticMatic

Answer (score 3):

**HAML**:

For automatic conversion from haml to sass you can use this gist: https://gist.github.com/3898955. If you want to automate even more the workflow process, you can use https://github.com/alexnj/SublimeOnSaveBuild sublime package to run the command on file save.

**SASS**:

For SASS here is the needed setup. https://gist.github.com/3899112.

For automatic conversion on save, the same rules are applied here too, but it's important to include the `.sass` and `.haml` extension in `SublimeOnSaveBuild.sublime-settings` file.

So your file should look like this:

```
{
    "filename_filter": "\\.(css|js|sass|less|scss|jade|haml)$",
    "build_on_save": 1
}
```

You can extend this list at your own wish.